# How did the vibranium lift Sokovia?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, avengers-age-of-ultron

In the Age of Ultron, vibranium seems to be placed in strategic locations underneath the city of Sokovia, so that a massive segment of earth is enclosed in some sort of force field defined by the vibranium locations.  Then that massive segment of earth is somehow lifted high into the sky, so that it can be dropped as if it were a massive meteor.  But this plan is dashed because Tony and Thor are somehow able to collaborate, with F.R.I.D.A.Y.'s guidance, to reverse the effect of the vibranium, so that the large segment of earth is blown to bits before it lands on the planet surface.

**How does this work?**

What is the force field being generated around the vibranium?  How does the forcefield work?  How is the large segment of earth being lifted into the sky?  And what do Tony and Thor do to cause the forcefield to collapse?

Comment: I thought Ultron was using the vibranium to power massive repulsors

Comment: My understanding was that the vibranium had nothing to do with lifting it. It was just used to reinforce the ground under the town so that it could be lifted without falling apart.

Comment: @Junuxx If that were an answer, I would vote for it.

Comment: @Nerrolken: Thanks, but it's just how I interpreted it when I saw the movie, and basically only a guess, since I got nothing to back it up. So I think it would be a bad answer :P

Comment: @Junuxx It's also how I interpreted it both times I saw the movie. There are quotes to back that up in the screenplay, if anybody has a copy of it.

Comment: Using vibranium for reinforcement would be like making another fribee ;)

Comment: Are you Sachin?

Comment: @CodeMed: Never mind.

Answer (score 16):

Vibranium didn't lift the city. Giant engines did. The vibranium only served as a superstructure holding the "meteor" (and the machinery) together, like a skeleton holds our bags of meat.

Comment: @CodeMed I'll have to rewatch it when Blu-Ray comes out, frankly, I don't remember any forcefields, but I do remember stuff crumbling away at first. Vibranium doesn't generate forcefields, I don't think it does. It never has.

Comment: Bedrock is not dirt...